# Why is it necessary to specify the row property of a field when using formValidation.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, formvalidation-plugin

Looking at the [FormValidation](https://github.com/formvalidation/formvalidation.io) getting started docs, they use a `row: '.col-xs-5'` property in the script of their [Complex Form](http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/#complex-form) example. I'm trying to wrap my head around why this is necessary? Does it have something to do with properly displaying the feedback `message`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they use row option to give a size to error message according to input's size.

for example :

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
      <label class="control-label">Movie title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" />
</div>
```

the size of title input is `col-xs-8` and also you have to give a row option with `col-xs-8` to validation option to display the error message in correct width which is the size of input (`col-xs-8`).

```
 title: {
                row: '.col-xs-8',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The title is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 200,
                        message: 'The title must be less than 200 characters long'
                    }
                }
            }
```